# Tailwind appearance-none not working for Select tags

Tags: select, tags, tailwind-css, arrow-keys

I need to remove the arrow of the select tag, so I follow an example on Tailwind CSS: https://v1.tailwindcss.com/docs/appearance
I checked the link to tailwind.min.css already, but it still not work.
The arrow still there
[image]

May I ask if I forget some thing?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `appearance: none` *is* working in your screenshot. The arrow seems to be a `background-image` applied to the `<select>` element:

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's great observation, but how to solve the problem? The background-image come from tailwind.css, if we try to disable here, it may affect to the other select tags

Comment: You could consider overriding the `background-image` property.

Comment: It worked fine to me by injecting a `style = "background:none"`, thank you very much. However, is there any better solution for this workaround?

Comment: Yes, I would assume there is, but this seems to be out-of-scope of the original question regarding `appearance-none`.

Comment: Thank you @Wongin. At the beginning, I think this is an workaround. But if we consider Tailwind in deeper layers, they may also operate like this. There is not any wrong cause by this workaround. So I believe this is a good solution. Notice that we even don't need to add `appearance-none` to our tailwind class.

Comment: add ```bg-none``` to the select tag